# Android live app - Google Admob mediation with Facebook Ads shows only Test Ads

Tags: java, android, facebook, admob, mobile-ad-mediation

We have added mediation code for Facebook with Admob in Android Studio.

But After published live app in play store, my app does not showing live ads, it's showing only facebook test ads.

**NOTE** : App reviewed/Approved successfully in Facebook developer console.

We are using below code for mediation.

**build.gradle**

`implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:6.5.1.0`

**Ad Class.java**

```java
 adView = new AdView(context);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(context.getResources().getString(R.string.admob_adaptive_banner));
        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {

            }
        });
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        // Add banner to view hierarchy.
        llBanner.removeAllViews();
        llBanner.addView(adView);
```

I have issues in all ads but here I have put only banner ads for showing purpose.

Anyone please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in that version in theory causing it to always show test ads. They released two new version after that, which should fix it according to Facebook.

In my case for some reason it's the opposite. Everything was working fine in 6.5.1.0, and updating to 6.5.1.1 and then to 6.6.0.0 it shows test ads.